# convert ByteArray to NSData

Tags: ios4

I want convert ByteArray into NSData
How can i do?
please Help me

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're calling a ByteArray is actually a "char *", or more generally a pointer to some data.

Then you'll want to do [NSData dataWithBytes:pointer]. Read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html